# Why can't I use the support library in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I installed the support library through the Android Studio SDK Manager - it's checked.

However, when I try to import anything within `android.support`, I get that the import is not defined. Android also fails to auto-complete `android.support`.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: add support lib in dependency `in build.gradle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the support library to you build.gradle file like this:

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed the required SDK.
Tools > Android > SDK Manager > Extras
Install it first if you have not.

If you have installed, go to build.gradle in dependencies. Add the following code to it.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
}
```